# Is it possible to capture on-screen interactions using MediaCapture API in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

Here is the Microsoft documentation on media capture: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452798

My question is about capturing onscreen interactions. In this instance, I want to record and replay the game the user has just played.

I am using HTML and Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about media capture there are other classes that you can use.

I guess you have heard about a Robot Class in Java that captures media(more often it takes keystrokes) there is a class in C # sendKeys(its there in JavaScript also) i am sharing a link below this will help

This a CodeProject example which ues Sendkeys'
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32556/Auto-Clicker-C

There is also another process of capturing media using HTML 5 but i am sharing a link below this might help you
http://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/

This MSDN LInk will also help you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.mediacapture

HTML 5 Rocks also explains how to use media capture.Here is the Link

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: Does Windows 8 suuport getusermedia?